# Can I delete the external dependencies, header, and resource files in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, project

I just wondered if I can delete those files? I wanna do this only for my own comfort so I will see only source file in my project.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?

Comment: @László Koller Yes, when ever you create a new project in visual studio you actully see four times of subfolders under your project folder in the actual IDE, I want to delete those three subfolders and stick with only one so it will look better for my opinion.

Comment: What kind of project: ASP.NET MVC, console, etc?

Comment: @László Koller empty project

Comment: When I create an empty C# project in VS2013, it has only a References node and the `app.config` file. In C++ I see four empty folders with the names you suggest, but these are virtual folders (filters, in fact) in the solution explorer - not files. Perhaps you could explain more clearly  what you're referring to? An empty project in *which language* would be the minimum necessary information to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

For a console application project, like the classic "Hello World!" program, you only need the *Program.cs* file (no *AssemblyInfo.cs*, *App.config*, or References required):

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

For your reference the *AssemblyInfo.cs* and *App.config* files were both deleted, and all external References (Microsoft.CSharp, System, System.Core, System.Data, etc.) removed. The Visual Studio project consists of *HelloWorld.csproj* and *Program.cs*. Two files, that's it.

Naturally, this is a "does nothing, goes nowhere" program, but it does demonstrate a bare bones style C# project.

I hope this helps. Good luck.